# QNetworkAccessManager post-data array of arrays

Tags: php, qt, post, qnetworkaccessmanager

Is there a possibility to send an array of arrays as post-data via the QNetworkAccessManager::post function?

I'm sending this to my website:

```
QUrl login;
login.addQueryItem("name", "MyName");
login.addQueryItem("password", "CoolPassword");

QNetworkRequest oRequest("127.0.0.1/xampp/test.php");
m_oManager.post(oRequest, login.encodedQuery());
```

Which results in the following POST-data received by my test-webseite:

```
#var_dump($_POST);
array(2)
{
  ["name"]=> string(6) "MyName"
  ["password"]=> string(12) "CoolPassword"
}
```

This is what i expected.
But the website i'm trying to parse requires POST-data which looks like this:

```
#var_dump($_POST);
array(2)
{
  ["_method"]=> string(4) "POST"
  ["data"]=> array(1)
  {
    ["world"]=> array(1)
    {
      ["Account"]=> array(2)
      {
        ["name"]=> string(6) "MyName"
        ["password"]=> string(12) "CoolPassword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do i create this structure? Is this even possible with QNetworkAccessManager?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of goofing around and reading website-http-code, i have found the solution.

```
QUrl login;
login.addQueryItem("_method", "POST");
login.addQueryItem("data[world][Account][name]", "MyName");
login.addQueryItem("data[world][Account][password]", "CoolPassword");
```